# ruined database through 'rake db:setup'? (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

Yesterday, i was tryin' to setup up a fulltext search-engine named "Elasticsearch"  and i followed the instructions on Railscasts.com (http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1?view=comments&_=1345840910957) to integrate this search-engine onto my website.
I followed the tasks to the point where to call 'rake db:setup' and it "recreated" my whole database (didn't wanted that) and now nothing works. 
It seems like Rails recreated the db from the schema.rb, but it only creates the tables and the indexes and not the associated columns with it. 
http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/1535/bildschirmfoto20120825u.png

Im on _development db.

Running `rake db:setup` looked like this:

```
doanything_development already exists 
doanything_test already exists
-- create_table("admin_notes", {:force=>true})
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "admin_notes_id_seq" for serial column "admin_notes.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "admin_notes_pkey" for table "admin_notes"
   -> 0.1088s
-- add_index("admin_notes", ["admin_user_type", "admin_user_id"], {:name=>"index_admin_notes_on_admin_user_type_and_admin_user_id"})
   -> 0.0064s
-- add_index("admin_notes", ["resource_type", "resource_id"], {:name=>"index_admin_notes_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"})
   -> 0.0049s ...<br /><br />
Schema.rb looks like: " create_table "users", :force => true do |t|<br />
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",:null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",:null => false ... end <br />
```

And it created on my pgdb table "Sequences" columns like `"users_id_seq"`, which i hadn't before. Running '`rake db:migrate`' doesn't load any of the existing migrationfiles: e.x.

```
class AddSaltToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration <br/>
  def change <br/>
    add_column :users, :salt, :string <br/>
  end
end
```

versions are : ruby 1.9.3p194, Rails 3.2.6 and PostgreSQL 9.1.4

If someone could figure out what just happenend and how i can get my site working again.

Comment: OK i *solved* it i by running 'rake db:migrate:reset' and it reseted my db from scratch again. I strongly recommend to read what every cmd does to your app when u follow some tutorials.. thanks for concern

Answer (score 1):

If you ran rake db:migrate once. The migration for `AddSaltToUsers` may have  already ran. If so, there are a few ways to overcome this.

Either create a new migrations file, or manually edit `schema_migrations`, by removing the version number from that table and then re-running `rake db:migrate`. I would highly not recommend doing the latter, as it can screw up your migrations all together if you don't know what you are doing.

Hope that helps.